# How can I remove the append h2 tag after open class comes. I am trying, but not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="nav" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1433409929526_470">
    <li class="dropdown open" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1433409929526_469">
        <a href="http://192.168.1.112/mth_old_31/moodle28/message/index.php?viewing=recentconversations" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Unread messages (5)" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1433409929526_473">
            <span id="yui_3_17_2_3_1433409929526_472">5</span>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="open"><a title="Admin User will..." href="http://192.168.1.112/mth_old_31/moodle28/message/index.php?user1=2&amp;user2=4">
                <div class="message unread">    
                    <span class="msg-picture">
                        <img src="http://192.168.1.112/mth_old_31/moodle28/theme/image.php?theme=elfin28&amp;component=core&amp;image=u%2Ff1" alt="Picture of student user" title="Picture of student user" class="userpicture defaultuserpic" width="60" height="60">
                    </span>
                    <span class="msg-body">
                        <span class="msg-time">
                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>                                    
                        </span>
                        <span class="msg-sender">student</span>
                        <span class="msg-text">Admin User will...</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="myid" class="box-messages">Massage</h2>
</li>
<div class="block_action" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1432698699754_495">
    <input type="image" class="moveto customcommand requiresjs" alt="Move this to the dock" title="Dock block" src="http://192.168.1.112/mth_old_31/moodle28/theme/elfin28/pix/arrow.png" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1432698699754_494">
</div>
</ul>

<script>
    $("#Box1 ul.nav li.dropdown").append('<h2 id="myid" class="box-messages">Massage</h2>');

    $( "#Box1 ul.nav li.dropdown.open a span" ).click(function() { $( "h2#myid" ).remove();});
</script>
```

I am trying like this but not working. Where i am working plz help

Comment: You question is far from clear...can you please explain "not working" ? Is it lying on the couch watching TV all day ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the selector has to be evaluated later

```
$("#Box1 ul.nav").on('click', 'li.dropdown.open a span', function () {
    $("#myid").remove();
});
```

In your case when you are using `$( "#Box1 ul.nav li.dropdown.open a span" )` the `li` don't have the `open` class so the click handler will not get registered.

Comment: It is most probably the answer, but it's impossible to tell with the code posted by OP if this "open" class is added dynamically. No code indicates that and class is hardcoded in HTML example provided...

Answer (score 0):

You can chekout link which remove when there 'open' class otherwise add it.

```
jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/963/
```